# C++ Compare values of double and double*

Tags: c++, pointers, double

I have a variable of type `double *`, which I am initialising to 0 with the line:

```
double* angle = 0;
```

I then have a function which takes two variables of type `const CCoordinate`, and three variables of type `double *` as parameters. This function takes the values held by the `const CCoordinate` variables and returns three variables of type `double *` as returned by calculations performed within the function.

**EDIT**

The declaration for the function mentioned above is:

```
int InverseVincenty(const CCoordinate aStartPosition,
const CCoordinate aEndPosition,
double* aDistance,
double* aAngle12,
double* aAngle21);
```

**End Edit**

I am now trying to write my own function, which will use this function to calculate the three `double *` variables, and then perform its own calculation on the `double *` variables. However, it seems that I am trying to compare the values of `doubles` with the values of `double *`, and the compiler is giving me some errors saying that I can't do this...

The kinds of calculation I want to do are things such as:

```
if((a <= b + 5) || (a >= b -5)){
    //do something
}
```

where a is a `double` and b is a `double*`.

The compiler is telling me that it cannot convert from a 'double *' to a 'double', but I'm not trying to convert anything, just trying to compare the values held by both variables... Is this possible at all?

I would have thought that since the pointer is pointing to an address in memory that will hold a value that is of an equivalent data type to the other variable (i.e. double and pointer to a double), that this would be possible?

If not, can anyone suggest another way that I could compare their values?

Comment: `double *` is a pointer to a double (or perhaps an array of `double`). Are you allocating memory with `new` somewhere so these point to something? In general, you probably don't need to use pointers here.

Comment: @crashmstr He's using pointers to output the results of a function. He could also use references.

Comment: Why do you think you need a `double*` pointer to do what you need? If the function in question _returns_ those values, just pass in the addresses of local variables.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`). Notice that pointers and doubles are of different types (so incomparable). Learn how to use the debugger (`gdb`)

Comment: Are your three `double *`s related logically? If they are, you could just return a single struct containing all of them, and pass your parameters as plain `doubles`. Could you give us the function declaration?

Comment: Function declaration added.

Answer (score 5):

```
if((a <= *b + 5) || (a >= *b -5)){
    //do something
}
```

Notice that by doing `double* angle = 0;`You are **not** initializing the variable rather its pointer meaning angle will point to 0.
Any attempt to de-reference angle will cause a segmentation fault.

Quoting from your question:

*I would have thought that since the pointer is pointing to an address in memory that will hold a value that is of an equivalent data type to the other variable (i.e. double and pointer to a double), that this would be possible?*

This is not the case. You correctly say *the pointer is pointing to an address in memory that will hold a value that is of an equivalent data type to the other variable*. However you need to de-reference the pointer using the * operator to access the values that is pointed.
You might want to look at some introductory guide like: [this](http://karwin.blogspot.com/2012/11/c-pointers-explained-really.html)

Comment: Or just have `double angle = 0;`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I gave this a try, but I am now getting a console error that says: `CAUGHT:(UNKOWN EXCEPTION)... any ideas why this may be?

Comment: I can't just have `double angle = 0;` because the first function mentioned in my question requires parameters of type `double *`...

Comment: Then you should do: `*angle = 0`;

Answer (score 0):

`b` is a pointer so you need to dereference it to get the value.

`if((a <= *b + 5) || (a >= *b -5))`

You tell us about `angle` but then never mention it again. The above code requires that `b` points to a valid memory address.

You can call your functions and retrieve the result as follows.

```
void test(double *d)
{
    *d = 5;
}

double d;
test(&d); // store result in d
```

Or, using references

```
void test(double& d)
{
    d = 5;
}

double d;
test(d); // store result in d
```

Answer (score 0):

As with your function signature

```
int InverseVincenty(const CCoordinate aStartPosition,
const CCoordinate aEndPosition,
double* aDistance,
double* aAngle12,
double* aAngle21);
```

it looks, that the function will return these three `double` values via pointer references.

To call the function just provide three double variables

```
double aDistance;
double aAngle12;
double aAngle21;
```

and provide their addresses in the function call

```
InverseVincenty(aStartPosition,aEndPosition,&aDistance,&aAngle12,&aAngle21);
                                        //  ^          ^         ^
                                        // Note the address-of operators
```

afterwards you can go on with your `double` values as usual.